# Does go build include non go files in binary?

Tags: go

Does `go build` include other supporting files used in code and ships it along with exe?
For ex:

```
--> input.go - contains go code to read input from text file
--> inpdata.txt
```

when we do `go build`, does the `inpdata.txt` files get shipped as well?
if these supporting files are excluded, how do they get their input values which are being fed from external files?

I am trying to build a binary (`exe` file precisely for win-OS) using Golang.
After reading some of the documentation can understand clearly that the `go build` command which produces the exe file for win-OS ignores `_test.go` files and all `tesdata` folders.
Also referred to [`go build` binary package](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Binary_Only_Packages) in the documentation, mentioned this is applicable only to non source files only.

Comment: In your example, `inpdata.txt` is not included in the output binary. Suppose your program read `inpdata.txt` by `ioutil.ReadAll("./inpdata.txt")`, when your binary is run, your program will actually look for `<current working directory>/inputdata.txt"`. `<current working directory>` is usually where you run your program. So you need to ensure your `inputdata.txt` is beside your binary.

Comment: @LiyangChen Is there a way to include inpdata.txt to the binary? Usecase: Let's say if I'm shipping this binary somewhere, how can I ensure that inpdata.txt is always present, without explicitly passing all the required resource files to server?

Answer (score 2):

> Does go build includes non go files in binary?

By default, no: you need to embed them.

There are several approaches:

- [`skx/implant`](https://github.com/skx/implant) generates a go file from your non-go resource
- [`aprice/embed`](https://github.com/aprice/embed) uses `go generate`
- [`gobuffalo/packr`](https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr) uses code declaration
- [`unnoted/fileb0x`](https://github.com/unnoted/fileb0x) defines a Virtual Memory File System.